# c++ C2509 in definition of instructor using try: - catch

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, try-catch

In definition

```
A::A()
try: B()
{}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

In this code, I have C2509 error. 
When I try to go to definition(F12) in header file or (Ctrl+F12) in definition it doesn't work.

I tried

```
A::A()
{
 try
 { B();}
 catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

but this is impossible because in class `B` there is a `pure virtual` function.

I'm confused with the difference between

```
try: {}
catch
```

and

```
try{}
catch
```

Comment: neither error names nor shortcuts are universal for C++. You need to include the error message in the question verbatim

Comment: I think you've answered your question: "this is impossible because in class B there is a pure virtual function." 
You can't instantiate an abstract class - including inside initialiser lists.

Comment: @virgesmith Thank you for your answer, but why can I initialize abstract class after ' try: ', not in try { } ?

Comment: Is there any way to succeed compile ?

Comment: @장윤지 Why do you think you can initialize it after `try:` when you said yourself that there's an error when you do that?

Comment: There's a big difference between the two, but it has nothing to do with try-catch: the first tries to initialize a `B` subobject (and `A` must derive from `B`), the second tries to create an anonymous instance of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now *assuming* A derives from B. In which case 1) you can explicitly initalise an abstract base class but 2) you must instantiate it in the initialiser list, since it must be fully constructed *before* the body of A::A() is executed.

This works for me:

```
#include <stdexcept>

struct B
{
  B() { }
  virtual int f() = 0;
};

struct A : B
{
  A() try : B() { } catch(const std::exception&) { }

  int f() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
}
```

using g++ 5.4. I'm guessing your error (which you haven't provided) is due to some other problem, e.g. not deriving A from B, or a mismatch between the virtual function definitions in the two classes.

Comment: Thank you so much. As you assumed, A derives from B. Sorry for not telling that. I figured out I didn't initialize all virtual function. It helped a lot. ;)